# Indexing pure text files with MySQL. Use MySQL's full text indexing or grow your own?

Tags: mysql, database, full-text-search

I need to implement a text file indexer that can return documents containing a queried sentence.  For example:  Search("and the dog has many legs") would return Text1.txt.

The number of files being indexed is fairly limited, probably around 5000 and each file is probably around 30-50kb of text.

I'd be interested to hear opinions on whether to use the internal full text mechanism in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) or to implement my own tables and handle the indexing myself through code?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job that mySQL's [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) is well equipped for. I can't see a reason to reinvent the wheel when that is available. Just import your texts into a `text` field, index properly, and you're done.